# Prove identifiability of a nonlinear model with Markov Process

Tags: mathematical-statistics, markov-process, nonlinear, identifiability

I have the following statistical model where for $w \in (1,2,...,W)$, $\theta = (\eta, \mu, \sigma^2)$, and for fixed $\beta$

$$Y_w = f(\theta, \beta, w) + \gamma_w$$

where

$$\gamma_w \sim N(\gamma_{w+1}, \sigma_{\gamma}^2)$$

is a reverse random walk and

$$f(\theta, \beta, w) = \beta + (\eta - \beta)exp(-(log(w) - \mu)^2/2\sigma^2)$$

I want to prove that the parameters $\theta$ and $\sigma_{\gamma}$ are identifiable. In modeling, I also use the constraint $-\gamma_1 = \sum_{i = 2}^W \gamma_i$ which might be a necessary condition.

I'm not looking for a full proof (unless someone has one :). I'm just looking for some help getting in the right direction. I'm familiar with proving identifiability in linear regression models, but this nonlinear model with the Markov Process is a different question.

Any help would be great!